# Add optional hardware acceleration to RenderTargetBitmap

Tags: wpf, silverlight, hardware, acceleration, rendertargetbitmap

Is there an alternative to RenderTargetBitmap that can produce an image to be used with Image.Source & is hardware accelerated in .NET 3.5 sp1? Answers for .NET 4.0 are fine but I may not be able to use them.

People should vote for this if they find it would be helpful... like me.

http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1303525-add-optional-hardware-acceleration-to-rendertarget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at [BitmapCacheBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcachebrush.aspx)

That class is hardware accelerated (runs on the GPU) and can be used like any other brush (just create a Rectangle and set its Fill property to the brush).

Comment: Great answer, but sadly I needed this to work in .NET 3.5 sp1 for our current product.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer because I think its really the only one there is.